# Role of <ds:X509Data> in service provider metadata file in Saml 2.0

Tags: saml, x509, saml-2.0, opensaml

I have gone through number of SAML related questions and assume i have fair knowledge of how SAML 2.0 works. One thing i am unable to understand is the Role of  in the Service provider metadata.

Specs say that saml authentication request(samlp:AuthnRequest) will be base64 encoded. I did not see any specs where it is mentioned to signed the authentication request and then encode it?

Can someone please explain the role of Role of  in service provider metadata file?

Answer (score 0):

You can sign an authnrequest, also you can specify x509 data to be used to sign or encrypt.